# Blurred lines in Path with too many LineGeometry objects

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am trying to draw a path with lots of disconnected line segments on a XAML Canvas programmatically like so

```
        Path path = new Path();
        path.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
        path.StrokeThickness = 2.0;
        GeometryGroup geomGroup = new GeometryGroup();

        for (int i = 0; i < Samples.Count; ++i)
        {
            double f = Samples[i];

            Point a = new Point(i * dpixels, y_c - f * y_c);
            Point b = new Point(i * dpixels, y_c + f * y_c);

            LineGeometry line = new LineGeometry();
            line.StartPoint = a;
            line.EndPoint = b;
            geomGroup.Children.Add(line);
        }

        path.Data = geomGroup;
        canvas.Children.Add(path);
```

The problem is that when there are too many LineGeometry objects in the GeometryGroup, the lines become blurred. It's very confusing because it seems to depend entirely on the number of lines. If I add the exact same lines, but fewer of them, they are no longer blurred. What is going on here and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

David

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?